# Temporary memory error in Shiny with pdf viewer (UiOutput) and selectableTableOutput (shinyjqui package)

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, shinyjqui

I have a super strange problem that I can't seem to figure out - I suspect it has something to do with writing/reading from temp directory. So what I'm trying to do is a long story, but i've reduced the problem down to two simple tasks.

1. View an uploaded pdf (with `UiOutput`)
2. Use selectable table (from `shinyjqui` package)

I have no problem doing these seperately, however, if I try combine them into one shiny app it always results in a crash. Here's my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           # Input pdf
           fileInput("file1", "File"),
           # Display an editable table (from shinyjqui)
           selectableTableOutput("tbl", selection_mode = "cell")
    ),
    column(6,
           # display uploaded pdf
           uiOutput("pdfview")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # ---- pdf (1)
  addResourcePath("pdf", tempdir())
  
  test_file <- reactive({
    req(input$file1$datapath)
    readBin(con=input$file1$datapath,what = 'raw',n=input$file1$size)
  })
  
  observe({
    temp <- paste0(resourcePaths(), "/doc.pdf")
    writeBin(test_file(), temp)
    output$pdfview <- renderUI({
      tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="pdf/doc.pdf")
    })
  })
  # ---- pdf (1)
  
  
  
  # --- selectableTable (2)
  get_dummy_data <- reactive({
    # random dataframe
    data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3),col2 = c(1,2,3),col3 = c(1,2,3))
  })
  
  output$tbl <- renderTable(get_dummy_data(), rownames = TRUE)
  # --- selectableTable (2)
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that, if you run the above the selectable table will work, however, the moment you upload a pdf it crashes. Moreover, if you comment out chunk 2 (selectable table), the pdf viewer works (specifically used in browser - not shiny popup). Something funky is happening in memory, because if you run the app without chunk 2, the pdf viewer works, and then if you bring chunk 2 into the picture it crashes - but if you take away chunk 2 again and rerun it, it doesn't work at all (and it was in the same state as what it was when it worked originally), and I have to close and reopen the project for the pdf viewer to work. Here is the error:

```
Warning: Error in file: invalid 'description' argument
  46: file
  45: writeBin
  44: <observer> [C:/Users/Chroo/OneDrive//Clients//Sandbox_0080921/test_pdf_viewer.R#34]
   1: runApp
```

Any ideas what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some browsing I found a solution from @amrrs on https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1545522. The issue is related to binary reading and writing, hence the strange memory behavior. The issue can be circumvented by copying the input file instead, because then the conflict with `shinyjqui` is avoided.

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({
    req(input$file1)
     
     #Remove
     #test_file <- readBin(input$file1$datapath, what="raw") 
     #writeBin(test_file, "myreport.pdf")
     #cat(input$file1$datapath)

     # Replace
     file.copy(input$file1$datapath,"www", overwrite = T)



  output$pdfview <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="0.pdf")
  })

  })

})
```